# OpenGL moving vertices with mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse-picking

I am using legacy OpenGL and trying to move vertices around with the mouse. To test whether a vertex is clicked on I loop through all vertices and multiply them by the model and projection matrix before dividing by the w value. This works fine and is shown below:

```
for (Vertex *vertex : context->getMesh().vertices) {
        QVector4D vert(vertex->xPos, vertex->yPos, vertex->zPos, 1.0f);
        QVector4D transformedVert = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * vert;
        transformedVert /= transformedVert.w();
        if ((mappedX < (transformedVert.x() + 0.1) && mappedX > (transformedVert.x() - 0.1)) &&
            (mappedY < (transformedVert.y() + 0.1) && mappedY > (transformedVert.y() - 0.1))) {
            std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
            vertexPicked = true;
            currentVertex = vertex;
        }
    }
```

Then when I move the mouse I try to work backwards by first multiplying the current mouse coordinates by the same W value as in the first step and then multiplying by the inverse of the projection and model matrices. This moves the vertex around but not to where the mouse is.

```
  float mouseX = ((2.0f * event->x()) / width() - 1.0f);
  float mouseY = -((2.0f * event->y()) / height() - 1.0f);
  float x = (modelMatrix.inverted() * projectionMatrix.inverted() *
                (QVector4D(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1) * (projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * QVector4D(MousePicker::currentVertex->xPos, MousePicker::currentVertex->yPos, MousePicker::currentVertex->zPos, 1)).w())).x();

  MousePicker::currentVertex->xPos = x;
```

I am currently only trying to change the X coordinate.

Comment: Again you have do divide by `w`. Dived by the `w` component, after the transformation by the inverse model view and projection matrix (of course by the `w` component which is the result of the transformation be the inverse matrices).

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried that and it didn't have any effect. Shoud I be multiplying by the w component before i multiply by the inverse matrices?

Comment: No. The coordinate which is transformed by the inverse projection matrix has to be a normalized device coordinate (all components in range[-1, 1]).

Comment: This is the new code:

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have done that. I am now multiplying the mouse Coordinates by the inverse matrices and dividing by the w comonent. The vertices are moving way further than the mouse

Comment: You have a perspective projection. You have to know the depth of the vertex coordinate! `QVector4D(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1)` is a point on the far plane, but not the vertex coordinate in normalized device space. The normalized device space z coordinate is important too, because at perspective projection the view space x and y coordinate depends on the depth.